# Laravel 5.5 listen dynamically generated queues

Tags: laravel-5, jobs, laravel-5.5

My application requires to have dynamically generated queues with some prefix like "**process_user_1**", "**process_user_2**", "**process_user_n**"

The main idea is to separate execution of some jobs depends on model ID.

To run watcher I need execute command `php artisan queue:work --queue process_user_1`

I didn't find possibility to put pattern like

```
php artisan queue:work --queue process_user_*
```

And only one way what I found it is to run them manually each time before job is sent. But it's so dirty...

Maybe someone know another way?

**EXAMPLE:**

> I have 10 users. Each user has 100 jobs to process in queue.
>
> If I put them to one queue like "process_user_job" users will wait a
>   lot of time when jobs will be finished.
>
> So I want to separate queues to speed up result returning

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?